# ¿Cómo podría realizar un foreach con ChartJS?

Tags: laravel, foreach, chart.js

Estoy intentando realizar un foreach con la herramienta Chart.

Este es mi código:

```
{{-- Eventos click --}}
    var ctxBarEC = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
    console.log(events[0].Categoria);
    console.log(events[0].totalEventos);

    var miEventoClick = new Chart(ctxBarEC,{
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Test 1', 'Test2'],
            datasets: [{
                label: ['X'],
                data: '¿Cómo puedo realizar un foreach para enviarselo al parametro data?'
                backgroundColor:[
                    'rgba(102, 204, 255)',
                    'rgba(255, 102, 0)',
                ],
            }],
        },
    });
```

Obtengo un array de objetos los cuales sé como acceder a ellos pero me gustaría hacer un bucle para que los muestre todos.

Comment: Hola, aqui te dejo un link de StackOverflow en ingles, en el responden a la pregunta, quizas te sea de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488121/adding-a-for-loop-foreach-loop-for-charts-js

Comment: Gracias por la aportación @icortazar!

Comment: @icortazar No he podido resolverlo aún pero me ha servido para orientarme un poco más e intentar pensar una solución.

Comment: Me alegro de que haya ayudado!